# Function to change parts of data source instead of replacing path?

Tags: arcpy

Using local files on a remote desktop server is giving me some issues. Using a locally made mxd in ArcView on the remote desktop will keep the C:... start to the filepath, but the server accesses my local files with a C$... start to the file path. Is there an arcpy function that allows me to just replace the ":" with a "$"? I can only seem to find functions that entirely replace the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String manipulation will achieve your goal:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    dSource = lyr.workspacePath
    if dSource [1] == ":"
        outSource = str (dSource)
        outSource [1] = "$"
        lyr.replaceDataSource (outSource, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE") ## update second parameter with correct source type
```

Note that I'm assuming a file geodatabase. See [Layer method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) replaceDataSource if your source is something different.